# Writing a DataFrame to a Cassandra table in Java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Not finding exactly what I need here. Loads of code in scala and Python. Here is what I have:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

public class CassandraWriter {
    private transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CassandraWriter.class);
    private Dataset<Row> hdfsDF;

    public CassandraWriter(Dataset<Row> dataFrame) {
        hdfsDF = dataFrame;
    }

    public void writeToCassandra(String tableName, String keyspace) {
        logger.info("Writing DataFrame to table: " + tableName);

        hdfsDF.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode("overwrite")
                .option("table",tableName)
                .option("keyspace",keyspace)
                .save();

        logger.info("Inserted DataFrame to Cassandra successfully");
    }
}
```

Error I am getting when running is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which dependencies are you including for the project?

Comment: spark-hive_2.10
spark-mllib-local_2.10
spark-core_2.10
spark-sql_2.10
spark-cassandra-connector_2.11

Comment: Perhaps it's in my spark-submit command? Do i need to call out cassandra in that spark submit command?

Comment: the error is indicating that there is a missing class in the classpath. Looking at some Spark examples (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md) they are including the import `import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._`

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.*; at the top of my java class. This is greyed out in my IntelliJ because it's not being used

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Spark Cassandra Connector is included into resulting jar that you're submitting.

This either could be done via build so-called fat-jar, and submit it. For example here is example ([full pom is here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/pom.xml)):

```xml
...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
    <spark.scala.version>2.11</spark.scala.version>
    <scc.version>2.4.1</scc.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_${spark.scala.version}</artifactId>
       <version>${scc.version}</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_${spark.scala.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Or you can specify spark cassandra connector as package via `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.2`

Comment: This worked!! Now getting a new error. I'm creating a Spark session as I was before. Reading the dataframe. Then I'm creating a new session connecting to Cassandra. This works! Thankfully. I'm connected. but when i try to write to the table i get Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {169.91.111.198}:9042 Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /169.91.111.198:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/169.91.111.198:9042]

Comment: check that you can reach the node on the port 9042... Either you have firewall, or node could advertise incorrect address...